# Purchasing bekishes online

Tags: clothing, chasidut-hasidism

Does anyone know where I could get a bekishe online besides eBay? I need it to be online because I don't live anywhere near a place where I could normally go to a physical store for one.

Comment: google "bekishe for sale" and some other places showed up as well as E-bay. I cannot say anything about the results.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any websites I know of that would constitute online shopping but if you know your size and what style you want there as requested plenty of places that will ship to you. Here is one that I have used to buy pants and shirts that button right over left...

http://www.hasidicclothing.com/index.html

If you call and ask they may even be willing to send pictures of a few differing styles. Personally though for an item of this nature I prefer to buy in person and try it on as it is difficult to know if an off the rack item will always fit the same. I have two different kappotos and one is a 40 slim and one is a 42 but both are very similar in size

Comment: +1 Someone told me that shirts right over left is simlas isha (woman's clothing). please tell me why this is not a problem,

Comment: Bc they aren't women's shirts. Women's shirts are designed differently and also have room for female anatomy. What side a button on isn't significant enough to make a piece of clothing look like it was made for a woman. You would likely not notice the difference unless someone told you.

Comment: Thank you So you have a source? (Maybe)