# Where to get a Kapoteh online

Tags: chasidut-hasidism

Is there any place online where I could purchase a Chassidic kapoteh? I know there are places in NY where you can get them but I do not live in the North East.

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70539/759

Comment: Two suggestions: Call a place directly and ask if they can ship it. If they won't do this, I may be able to pick up the order and ship it to you. Try the 1st option. If it doesn't work, we'll try to arrange a chat room to exchange info.

Comment: Kapoteh is what litveshe rabbis wear. A bekeshe is the chassidishe version. There are minute differences. Then there is the Lubavitch version which is closer to the kapoteh. I'm not sure what they call theirs.